Migration from vanilla Spring MVC to Spring Boot - Controllers as folder names and directory index file
I'm switching from my vanilla Spring MVC based web app to Spring Boot (v3.2.5) and I can't seem to solve the problem of handling requests, which up until now has worked on a file system basis.
For example, I had the following files structure in the 'webapp' folder:
webapp
--index.jsp
--test1
----index.jsp
--test2
----index.jsp
...
--another-test
----index.jsp

The JSP is configured simply like this in application.properties:
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

Up to now, the request https://example.com/test1 and also https://example.com/test1/
automatically found and executed the file test1/index.jsp
Now both example.com/test1 example.com/test1/ return 404 error.
Of course, the request example.com/test1/index.jsp works fine, it processes and displays the code from "test1/index.jsp".
I would like to configure Spring so that if it doesn't find the Controller under the name "/test1" then that it tries to find the folder "test1" and if there is an "index.jsp" file in it then executes it and displays it.
Is there a solution for this?
In the Apache HTTP server configuration this option is called DirectoryIndex, but I haven't found anything similar for Spring. I suspect that WelcomePage might be used for this, but the documentation didn't help me and it doesn't work for me with folders welcome-pages: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.welcome-page

OK, if anyone is looking for a solution to this problem, two things that may be helpful:
Trailing slash match
In Spring 6 "trailing slash match" function is set to false and is deprecated. And this was an unpleasant surprise for many users.
Enabling this feature allows you to make, that /testlink/ works as /testlink. This is how it can be done:
@Configuration
public class PWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);
  }
}

BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN
In Spring deployed on Tomcat,  for the above file structure in the webapp folder, requests to urls example.com/test1, example.com/test2, example.com/another-test worked fine and simply executed index.jsp from those folders. For example: example.com/test1 was internally forwarded to example.com/test1/index.jsp.
My imperfect solution: in the Spring Boot version, I created such a controller for all folders containing "index.jsp":
@Controller
public class DefaultControllers {

  @RequestMapping({"/test1","/test2",...,"/another-test"}) 
  public String pn(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String matchedPath = String.valueOf(req.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE));
    return matchedPath.substring(1)+"/index"; 
  }  
}

However, I still haven't managed to get it to not need to list the names of those folders in @RequestMapping.
My goal is this:

My Spring Boot application with embeded Tomcat is running, on port 443, at https://localhost/

I create folder "aaabbccc" in "webapp" folder.

I create in the "aaabbccc" folder an "index.jsp" file with the contents:
<% out.print("hello world"); %>

Request to url https://localhost/aaabbccc outputs with "hello world", without any additional configuration.


This would allow to instantly add a new mapping while the application is running, just by adding a single folder and file in the file structure.
This was possible in an application deployed on Tomcat.
Do you have any idea how to achieve this in Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat?
